# Join postgresql timestamp on hour interval

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to classify the shifts using the timestamp, start hour and end hour.

However the result is hawful because of the fact that the night interval is bewtween 22 and 6 hours.

[image: Shifts Table]

```
SELECT
  w.timestamp,
  s."ShiftName",
  sum(w.quantity) AS "qt"
FROM stats AS w
LEFT JOIN shifts AS s
ON EXTRACT(HOUR FROM timestamp) BETWEEN s."StartHour" AND s."EndHour"
GROUP BY 2,1
```

[image: Result]

Even with >= and <= the result doesn't change and i can't use window functions in joins.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT
  w.timestamp,
  s."ShiftName",
  sum(w.quantity) AS "qt"
FROM stats AS w
LEFT JOIN shifts AS s ON EXTRACT(HOUR FROM timestamp) >= s."StartHour" AND EXTRACT(HOUR FROM timestamp) < s."EndHour"
GROUP BY 2,1
```

Between check if the value is greater than or equal to the low value and less than or equal to the high value. Because of the end hour is the same as de start hour of the next row you need to check >= AND <.

I think it could be work (I "splited" the night interval):

```
SELECT
  w.timestamp,
  s."ShiftName",
  sum(w.quantity) AS "qt"
FROM stats AS w
LEFT JOIN shifts AS s ON 
    (s."StartHour" < s."EndHour" AND EXTRACT(HOUR FROM timestamp) >= s."StartHour" AND EXTRACT(HOUR FROM timestamp) < s."EndHour") OR
    (s."StartHour" > s."EndHour" AND ((EXTRACT(HOUR FROM timestamp) >= s."StartHour" AND EXTRACT(HOUR FROM timestamp) <= 23) OR
                (EXTRACT(HOUR FROM timestamp) >= 0 AND EXTRACT(HOUR FROM timestamp) < s."EndHour"))
    )           
GROUP BY 2,1
```

Comment: That would've been too easy to be true: it gets afternoon and morning right but all nights are null

Comment: At night you should split the interval like 22 to 24 and 24 to 6.

Comment: I rewrite the query spliting the night interval.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit complicated, because the times are not in order.  I suspect you want:

```
SELECT w.timestamp, s."ShiftName", sum(w.quantity) AS "qt"
FROM stats w LEFT JOIN
     shifts s
     ON (s."StartHour" <= s."EndHour" AND
         EXTRACT(HOUR FROM timestamp) >= s."StartHour" AND
         EXTRACT(HOUR FROM timestamp) < s."EndHour" AND
        ) OR
        (s."StartHour" > s."EndHour" AND
         EXTRACT(HOUR FROM timestamp) >= s."StartHour" OR
         EXTRACT(HOUR FROM timestamp) < s."EndHour"
        )
GROUP BY 2,1
```

Comment: It still spits things like 3 AM as "Afternoon" which is obviously wrong :-( but it's a nice input

Comment: @GiulioVannini . . . Something is wrong with your logic or interpretation.  "3 AM" does not meet the condition for "Afternoon".  Perhaps you are confusing it with "3 PM".